# bitcoin-qt compiles successfully but runs fail

Tags: client, bitcoin-core

I have compiled bitoin-qt, PTS coin and other alt-coins successfully, but they can't run concurrently.

I use MinGW4.4, QT 4.8.5 downloaded from website and QT creator 2.8.1.

This is my .pro setting:

```
BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mgw44-mt-s-1_53
BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/boost_1_53_0
BOOST_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib
BDB_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
BDB_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/openssl-1.0.1e/include
OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/openssl-1.0.1e
MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs
MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/miniupnpc-1.8
```

And I uncommented this code for MinGW4.4 doesn't support it (I've used MinGW 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8; but they all failed just at compiling) :

```
#win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat
```

These are all compiled by MinG W4.4 successfully, but both the resulting debug and release executables fail to run. I have copied the Qt DLLs to the EXE direction. When I debugged it, it crashed before entering the main source.

**======================UPDATE edit==========================**

I know it's because of leveldb,but I don't know what's wrong with my compiling leveldb:

```
 TARGET_OS=NATIVE_WINDOWS mingw32-make libleveldb.a libmemenv.a
```

When I use another altercoin leveldb source code,the error solves.But I use back to the original leveldb source code,the program breaks again.

Comment: You leave way too much details out of your question. By context, it's clear you're using Windows. How have you organized the source code tree? What environment variables have you set? And most importantly: what switches are you passing off to the compiler?

Comment: Furthermore, I believe this question would be more appropriate in Stack Overflow...

Comment: I write log to debug it and find it breaks at:`pblocktree = new CBlockTreeDB(nBlockTreeDBCache, false, fReindex);` And can't enter CBlockTreeDB